# Rails 3.2 can't find my tests, thinks they are in "test" directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

I am trying to user RSpec and failing to configure MiniTest/Spork/Capybara/Guard. My Gemfile is all set and I ran the command to install RSpec.

Unfortunately, the application continues to "think" my tests are in the `test` directory. Sorry, they're not. They're in `specs`, and the framework should really know that.

Maybe it's some sort of configuration issue from trying to get the impossible stack above to work that I still have in place. Where does Rails "decide" in which directory to look for tests? `RSpec` itself is the one that created the `spec` directory.

Comment: Are you sure that `rspec-rails` gem is both in your `:development` and `:test` group in Gemfile? Rails does this job, if it is included in `:development` group too.

Comment: GREAT CATCH. I thought it was, but I had type: gem 'rspec-rails', :group => [:test, :developement]

Comment: Added it as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `rspec-rails` should be included in your `Gemfile`.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end
```

Make sure it is added in both `:development` and `:test` group.